# Transform and accumulate with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Coming from Python I wonder if C++ nowadays has some good functional things there are in Python.

Currently I am trying to figure out how to produce a sum of some elements using indexes instead. For example with Python I would:

```
a = [ ... ]
b = [ ... ]

sum(map(lambda i: a[i] * 2 - b[i + 1], range(len(a)))
```

So here I generate a new array where each element is determined by some index arithmetic.

In STL there are `transform` and `accumulate`, but they take iterators as arguments. This would be OK if only on each step I needed to change a concrete element. Here I need to use index.

Also with `transform` I have to specify the array I need to put the results to. Is there a way the resulting array could be generated on the fly and then returned? Something like Python's `map` does.

Because in such case it's really easier to write a simple for-loop.

Comment: what's the output of this ? Sorry not aware of Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create an intermediate array, just leave `std::transform` out of the picture. All you need is `std::accumulate` to sum the intermediate result. But, as you've noted, this involves jumping through a few hoops to get the index given an iterator.

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

std::accumulate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0,
                [&](int acc, int& a_elem) {
                    auto index = std::distance(a, &a_elem);
                    return acc + a[index] * 2 - b[index + 1];
                })
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab990e43f305ed8e)

This can be cleaned up quite a bit if you can use [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) instead. This will allow you to generate a range of integers that can be used as indices, very similar to your Python example.

```
boost::accumulate(boost::irange<unsigned>(0, boost::size(a)), 0,
                  [&](int acc, int index) {
                    return acc + a[index] * 2 - b[index + 1];
                  })
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/292972a1abe76665)

Comment: Oh, great. The one with boost range looks almost exactly like I wanted.